# Can I get matched variable in htaccess RewriteCond?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I access the matched variable in the a rule like this one ?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://example\.com/dir[0-9]/?(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ other_dir(MATCHED_STRING)/images/$1 [L]
```

I would like the url : http://example.com/dir1
to redirect all its images to /other_dir1/images/$1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **%** to access back refernces from a RewriteCond. So in your example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://example\.com/dir[0-9]/?(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ other_dir%1/images/$1 [L]
```

The `%1` will be replaced with what was matched in the RewriteCond in the HTTP referer.